# UPDATE with WITH-AS clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, temp-tables, table-variable

When I run the following script, `Original_Table` gets updated by the `UPDATE` statement

```
WITH temp AS (
    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by x order by y) row_num, x, z
    FROM Original_Table )

UPDATE temp set z = a + (select ISNULL(SUM(a),0) from temp A where A.x= temp.xand A.row_num < temp.row_num)
```

But when I replace WITH with the following

```
CREATE TABLE
    #temp
(
    row_num INT NOT NULL ,
    x INT   NOT NULL,
    a DECIMAL   NOT NULL ,
    z DECIMAL    NULL 
);

insert into #temp
    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by x order by y) row_num, x, z
    FROM Original_Table 

UPDATE temp set z = a + (select ISNULL(SUM(a),0) from temp A where A.x= temp.xand A.row_num < temp.row_num)
```

the `UPDATE` updates only the `#temp` table but not `Original_Table`

Why is that?

Comment: This is known as common table expression. For MS Sql see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I don't see any attempt to update `original_table`.

Comment: the `UPDATE` is the same. Only `WITH` changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example updates `temp` which is based on a query from `Original_Table` by way of the CTE. The base table is updated when the CTE is updated. As explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx#Anchor_1), the CTE is *within* the scope of the `UPDATE` statement.

The second example queries `Original_Table` and saves the result in a *new table*: `#temp`. The temporary table is then updated. There is no *magic memory* that ties the rows in `#temp` back to the rows in `Original_Table`, and you probably wouldn't want one.

Answer (score 1):

That very last statement

```
UPDATE temp
 set z = a + (select ISNULL(SUM(a),0)
               from temp A where A.x= temp.x
                and A.row_num < temp.row_num)
```

only updates some table name "temp". There is nothing in the statement that references `Original_Table`

Comment: Yes it does, because Original_Table is referenced within the statement. Your first script is one single statement--a long and reasonably complex Common Table Expression that performs an update. The second script is three statements: a CREATE (temp) TABLE, followed by an INSERT, followed by an an UPDATE.